# How to know which rules were applied during autoformatting using PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, rules, autoformatting

I am trying to figure what rules PhpStorm is using in my current file during autoformatting via "Reformat Code" so I can tweak it better. Is there way to view the rules that were applied?

A more concrete example:

I have a file with this code:

```php
public function rules(): array {
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
       ['foo', 'bar'],
    ];
}
```

that is converted into:

```php
public function rules(): array {
    return array_merge(parent::rules(),
        [
            ['foo', 'bar'],
        ]
    ]
}
```

but I don't know which rule I have to tweak in order to not apply that change. I also want to be able to tell in other cases which ruleset caused which change during autoformat.

Is that possible and if so how?

Comment: Not an answer but a hint: you can copy your code, go to the Code Style settings and paste it in the code sample area of the desired tab. Then, once you change any formatter option on that tab it will apply reformatting to your custom code / live preview. Possible downside: the code area is narrow so the line length in rather limited and code wrapping will happen sooner.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can check that by selecting a code block and then `Help | Find Action | Adjust code style settings`.

But, please be aware that it is not all that precise, it can and does miss things. In your particular case, try playing around with `Function/constructor call arguments` and `Array initializer` in Wrapping and Braces.